# Next.js: Router.push with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I'm using next.js for rebuilding an app for server side rendering.
I have a button that handles a search request.

In the old app, the handler was this one:

```
search = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.push({
        pathname: '/results',
        state: {
            pattern: this.state.searchText,
        }
    });
}
```

In the results class, I could get the state date with this.props.location.state.pattern.

So now I'm using next.js:

```
import Router, { withRouter } from 'next/router'

performSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    Router.push({ pathname: '/results', state: { pattern: this.state.searchText } });
};
```

In the results class, I use

```
static async getInitialProps({req}) {
    return req.params;
}
```

I'm not sure if I have to add this to my server.js:

```
server.get('/results', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/results', req.params)
})
```

However, the function getInitialProps throws an error because req is undefined. Long text, short question: how to pass state or params to another page without using GET parameters?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

In `next.js` you can pass query parameters like this

```js
Router.push({
    pathname: '/about',
    query: { name: 'Someone' }
})
```

and then in your next page (here in `/about` page), retrieve the `query` via the `router` props, which needs to be injected to `Component` by using `withRouter`.

```js
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

class About extends React.Component {
  // your Component implementation
  // retrieve them like this
  // this.props.router.query.name
}

export default withRouter(About)
```

Comment: ```js
this.props.router.query.name
```
it's showing -- Type erroe -- cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: same issue here, when it push it won't load the page with an error of cannot read property of req.user (this is what i pass). but if i hit refresh it loads

Comment: @ggnoredo my guess is you're using `req.user` in `getInitialProps` but when routing is done in client side there is no `req` object. `req.user` only exists when Next.js is rendering in the server.

Comment: @PrithweeDas didn't know that. I've switched to query parameter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a question, Does this state persist when the pages are reloaded?

Comment: if you're talking about query parameters then yes, you'll have a `?name=Someone` in your url and if you refresh still it'll be the same.

Comment: This pollutes the UR.  Isn't there a feature like react router?

Comment: There is no such feature. you can find more about this here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/771 @UmakantPatil

Comment: this seems to work only for single nested fields. What about objects that have multiple nested fields?

Comment: @ZenVentzi I can't find a feature like that, don't know if a package simulate that. Generally I use local storage to save the objects, and retrieve them when needed. Just make sure that I clean things regularly not eat the all the space. I hope future release put state when page switching are done client side.

Comment: can i pass object?

Comment: Please update answer for NextJS 13

Answer (score 40):

If you want your url remain clean, make a small addition to Prithwee Das's answer like below.

```
Router.push({
    pathname: '/about',
    query: { name: 'Someone' }
}, '/about');
```

Now you can access props in your component using props

```
...

const YourComponent = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.router.query.name);
    }, [props.router.query]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            ...
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

...
```

Comment: This one works for me! However if I pass nested object, their children all become empty (" ") no idea why...

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(obj) in router push, then JSON.parse(obj) in useEffect hook

Comment: Awesome addition!

Answer (score 21):

I don't know whether this supports SSR, but I had to do it as follows to avoid the error `cannot read property 'query' of undefined`.

This uses `useRouter` hook to get access to the url, imported as below.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
```

Assume you want to pass data `{name:'Someone'}` from `Component A` to `Component B`.

In `Component A`,

```
const router = useRouter();

router.push(
  { pathname: "/path_of_component_b", query: { name: "Someone" } },
  "path_of_component_b"
);
```

In `Component B`,

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  alert(router.query.name); // Alerts 'Someone'
}, [router.query]);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want 'clean' urls, one way to go about it is to add onClick handler to your link and store required information in context/redux store. It easy to implement if you already have one.

```
<Link href='...'>
  <a onClick={()=>{dispatch(....)}}>Link<a/>
<Link>
```

Comment: You don't want to put into Redux too many things. If only one or two components are interested in that state, better to avoid Redux or usage of context

Comment: Yeah, it's basically a hack. But because sending deep nested data with Next.js Router is hard/impossible, it has some limited uses

Answer (score 3):

***In Next.js 13 app directory***, you can't pass the params like the previous answers, there is no way to do this using Next.js navigation system. however, you can use plain javascript to do this by using `history.pushState(state, "", url)` you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Below is an example of how to use it.

**First page:**

```
"use client";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function First() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  function handleClick() {
    history.pushState({ email: "example@example.com" }, "", pathname + "/second");
    router.push("second");
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Navigate to Second page</button>;
}
```

**Second page:**

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const myState = history.state;//store the state variable outside the component

export default function Second() {
  const [routeState, setRouteState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setRouteState(myState);
  }, []);

  return <h1>{routeState.email}</h1>;
}
```

***Note: this approach will only work in client components and the state will disappear once you refresh the browser, so the use cases of this approach will be very limited. If you want a more convenient way to pass the data you can use query params or localstorage***

Comment: Won't calling both `history.pushState` and `router.push` add two history entries? And on the second page using `const myState = history.state` outside the component means this will only execute once when the component loads, not when it is rendered, and not in subsequent renders.

Comment: yes I mentioned that on refresh the state will disappear, this means the state will be available only on the initial load. however, I think it is time to think about using localStorage as a state or using the query params

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add in @Ahmet Firat Keler answer. If you want make your URL to remain clean and pass the data as well, we can do it using `"next/link"`.

`as` props works fine with  `next/link` and you can hide query parameters with `next/link` as well.

```
<Link href={`/blogs/${item.slug}?id=${item.id}`} as={`/blogs/${item.slug}`} passHref>
    <a href="" className="hover:text-cyanBlue">
        Read More
    </a>
</Link>
```

But keep in mind, this won't work if you set `target="_blank"` to anchor tag or open link to the next tab of the browser

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the App Router features and conventions that were introduced in Next.js 13, most of the previous answers to this question do not apply or work at all. For instance, the pathname string has been removed and replaced by usePathname(), and the query object has been removed and replaced by useSearchParams().

This page has the answers you're looking for: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can achieve something similar using query parameters:

```
const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = () => {
    router.push({
      pathname: '/secondPage',
      query: { myState: 'yourStateValue' },
    });
  };
```

Comment: You can't do that in the latest NexJS. Only a single `string` is accepted as the param to `router,push`. You get the error `Argument of type '{ pathname: string; query: { myState: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`