# Pass object to query on Router.push NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

Im new to NextJs and im trying to pass an object to another page through a component. I'll post the code and explain better what im trying to do:

The object is like this:

```
objectEx = {
  name: 'name',
  description: 'description'
}
```

**This is the main component:**
Im trying to pass the object in the Router.push

```
export default class ComponentDummy extends Component {

  handleSubmit = value => e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Router.push({
      pathname: '/OtherPage'
      query: { **PASS AN OBJECT HERE** } //what im trying is: query: { objectEx: objectEx},
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the page that im trying to receive the object in query**

```
const OtherPage = ({ query }) => {
  return( 
    <div> 
      Do Stuff with the object here
    </div>
  )
}

OtherPage.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
  return { query }
}
```

Then on the page above im trying to access the object like:

```
query.objectEx.name
```

This is not working as I thought I would. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182740/7785337

Comment: Not really, as on the example they are passing a parameter and im trying to pass an entire object

Comment: @kivul did you find a solution? I'm new to next as well, but wouldn't it work to pass the whole object to the query like so:

`Router.push({
      pathname: '/OtherPage'
      query: myObj
    })
`

EDIT: But yeah, I guess it still won't work for nested fields..

Comment: @ZenVentzi i didnt, i just passed a lot of fields instead :|

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based, please check stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Well, first thing is you passed object as a query param.

Router.push({
      pathname: '/OtherPage'
      query: { data: objectEx} 
    }

So, in order to access the object in the OtherPage, you need to fetch this inside componentDidMount.

componentDidMount() {
let data = window.location.search;
console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work?  
TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | readonly string[] | readonly number[] | readonly boolean[] | null | undefined'.   Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly boolean[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to pass Object as query param for next/router. You need to pass string

```js
Router.push({
   pathname: '/OtherPage'
   query: { objectEx: JSON.stringify(objectEx) },
}
```

Keep in mind, that you'll need to parse it your self

```js
const params = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(router.query.objectEx))
```

Better yet to use lib like qs for stringifying objects to URL params.