# Next.js: how do I redirect with state without using URL queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a page`/register`. After the user fills in their username and password on the page, I want to redirect them to another page, `/new-user`, where they can fill the basic information about them. The submit button on the second page will call the API to create a new user.

In React, this is easy with `react-dom-router`. How do I do the same with Next.js? [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182529/next-js-router-push-with-state)
provided a solution with URL queries, but I don't want the user to see `?password=NextJSisHard` in the URL.

Comment: You can hold the state in [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass it between pages.

Comment: Is it generally a good idea to put passwords into React Context?