# router.push with parameters in Next.js

Tags: next.js

How can I use `router.push` (or something similar) in Next.js to redirect one page to another while keeping the params and anchors?

Example:
`site.com/blog/12#comments?param=somevalue&param2=anothervalue` => `site.com/blog/some-blog-post#comments?param=somevalue&param2=anothervalue`

Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182529/next-js-router-push-with-state) - you might have to push the existing state explicitly.

Comment: I just found `router.push({ pathname: "somewhere", query: { ...router.query })`. However, I'm still looking for a way to get the anchor link.

Comment: What is the anchor link here? What value do you want to get/preserve?

Comment: anchor* (hash). In the example above, I mean `#comments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.push` can take a partial URL object, so you can specify `hash` there:

```
router.push({
    pathname: "somewhere",
    query: router.query,
    hash: typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.location.hash : undefined,
});
```

I check if `window` is defined because of Next.js SSR. If you don't have SSR you don't need this check.

Comment: Note that the `window` check is not needed. `router.push` can only be called from the client-side where `window` is always defined.